# Aggregate pandas dataframe consistently with the same values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, aggregate

I'm trying to exclude unnecessury rows from pandas dataframe with aggregating by one column.  The dataframe looks like this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'date':[20191121]*10,
   'time':[100000]*10,
   'last':[64131,64131,64130,64130,64130,64131,64131,64132,64130,64130],
   'vol':[1]*10})

print(df1)
       date    time   last  vol
0  20191121  100000  64131    1
1  20191121  100000  64131    1
2  20191121  100000  64130    1
3  20191121  100000  64130    1
4  20191121  100000  64130    1
5  20191121  100000  64131    1
6  20191121  100000  64131    1
7  20191121  100000  64132    1
8  20191121  100000  64130    1
9  20191121  100000  64130    1
```

I would like to get the dataframe like this:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'date':[20191121]*5,
   'time':[100000]*5,
   'last':[64131,64130,64131,64132,64130],
   'vol':[2,3,2,1,2]})

print(df2)
       date    time   last  vol
0  20191121  100000  64131    2
1  20191121  100000  64130    3
2  20191121  100000  64131    2
3  20191121  100000  64132    1
4  20191121  100000  64130    2
```

Could you help me to solve this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum`, but is also necessary add helper Series for consecutive values of `last` to `groupby`:

```
g = df1['last'].ne(df1['last'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df1.groupby(['date','time','last', g], sort=False, as_index=False)['vol'].sum()
print(df)
       date    time   last  vol
0  20191121  100000  64131    2
1  20191121  100000  64130    3
2  20191121  100000  64131    2
3  20191121  100000  64132    1
4  20191121  100000  64130    2
```

If want working with consecutive values of all 3 columns:

```
c = ['date','time','last']
g = df1[c].ne(df1[c].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

df = df1.groupby(c + [g], sort=False, as_index=False)['vol'].sum()
print(df)
       date    time   last  vol
0  20191121  100000  64131    2
1  20191121  100000  64130    3
2  20191121  100000  64131    2
3  20191121  100000  64132    1
4  20191121  100000  64130    2
```

Comment: beautiful hack the use of `shift()` in this case